# Un aviso cada mes el mismo día

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo una aplicación donde el usuario pone el día del mes en el que se le cobrará un importe y también que indique con cuantos días quiere que se le avise.
Aquí pongo un ejemplo:
El usuario tiene un importe el 9 de cada mes y quiere que se le avise con 5 días de antelación.
Lo que estoy intentando hacer es compararlo con segundos es decir 1 día tiene 86400 segundos.

```
if (isset($row['puntual'])) {
            $fechaPuntual = strtotime($row['puntual']);
            $mostrarFormato = date('d/m/y', $fechaPuntual);
            $restaFecha = $fechaPuntual - $fechahoy;
            if($restaFecha < $fechaviso){
                $avisos++;
            }                              
        }
```

Aquí tengo un ejemplo de lo que tengo hecho con un importe en un día exacto.
Y yo lo que estoy intentando hacer es lo mismo pero con el día de cada mes.

Comment: Hay muchas formas de hacer esto la verdad. Mi recomendación es que crees una tarea CRON que ejecute el script cuando lo necesite (en este caso el dia X de cada mes) y dicho script será el encargado de notificar al usuario según ser requiera. Echa un vistazo a: https://geekytheory.com/programar-tareas-en-linux-usando-crontab

Comment: Pues yo no veo porque cerrarla, y me parece una pregunta muy interesante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues si tienes la fecha, para que complicarte la vida sumando todos los meses en segundo, cuando puedes restar?

A que voy con esto. Si definiste por ejemplo día 05/04/2017, saca 05 y lo defines el mes trayendo del servidor, para que tengas 05/05/2017, 05/06/2017, etc.

Vale decir:

```
fechaDada = '05/04/2017';
$puntual = substr(fechaDada, 2);

if (isset($row['puntual'])) {
    $fechaFinal = date_create(date("Y").'-'.date("m").'-'.$puntual);

    $diaAviso = strtotime ( '-5 day' , strtotime($fechaFinal) );
    $diaAviso = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $diaAviso );
    $diaActual = date_create(date("Y").'-'.date("m").'-'.date("d"));

    if ($diaAviso <= $diaActual && $diaActual <= $fechaFinal){

        $segundoFinal = new DateTime($fechaFinal.' 00:00:00'));
        $enTiempo = $segundoFinal - time();

        if($enTiempo > 0){
          $mostrarFormato = $puntual.'/'.date("m").'/'.date("Y");
          $avisos++;
        }
    }                          
}
```

Esencialmente marca día 05, le va colocando el mes y el año según la fecha del servidor. Resta 5 días para saber desde cuando empezamos a avisar, y por ultimo estima si la fecha actual es menor a la fecha final.

Espero que te ayude, o al menos orientar. Exito! :D

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Intentaré aplicarlo

Comment: Cualquier cosa me avisas! Éxito en tu proyecto :D

Answer (score 1):

Una solución es seleccionar desde la base de datos los registros a los que corresponde avisar cada día, haciendo la resta de fechas en la propia consulta, de este modo tienes directamente los avisos y no necesitas hacer la conversión a segundos.

Por ejemplo:

```
"select * from mi_tabla where fecha_puntual = fecha_pago - interval n_dias day"
```

Y me uno a los comentarios anteriores en que lo más comodo sería ejecutar la tarea con un cron.

Answer (score 0):

Yo una solución que veo viable y factible es que guardes el día del mes en el que el usuario quiere pagar y con cuantos días de antelación se le tiene que avisar.

Luego coloques un CRON que pase todos los días a una hora determinada y compruebe con un servicio a quienes tiene que pasar el pago y a quienes tiene que avisar la antelación.

De esta forma solo pasas un proceso diario por ejemplo para que no sea vea afectado el servidor demasiado o el impacto no sea tan alto a las 6 de la mañana.

Comment: ¿Puedes aportar algo de código para guiar al usuario?